# Merging two .htaccess directives into one

Tags: .htaccess

I have two directives in my site's root .htaccess file.

The purpose of the first is to redirect all non-www requests to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The purpose of the second is to redirect all non-SSL requests to SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Is there a way of merging these into a single .htaccess directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule to enforce both `https` and `www` in a single request :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Note that the rule above also redirects subdomains to https. If you don't want the rule to apply to subdomains  you can exclude them using a Rewrite condition.  Put the following line above the RewriteRule directive if you have subdomains

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(sub1\.domain\.com|sub2.domain.com)$
```

Full code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#exclude sub.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: That seems to work, thank you, though I notice I have to include the code block in WordPress `.htaccess` files, too.